# Linux Shared Object Library Linkage

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, elf

I have a library I want to use. I don't have the source code for it but it contains a function I'd like to use. It is a normal x86-64 shared object with some JNI code in it and nothing that special. My problem is now that the library references to `libm.so`. What now happens is quite strange and I did not expect it. When I try to run it, it tells me that `libm.so` has an invalid ELF-header, what makes sense because `libm.so` is just a reference file to `libm.so.6` which is the actual library file.

Now my question is how to correct that? I'm really surprised that the operating system doesn't handle that correctly since every program will reference to `libm.so` and not `libm.so.6` since it should be at least somewhat version independent.

**EDIT:** I did an `strace` and `libm.so` seems to be just the tip of the iceberg... My library is referencing to many common standard libraries of linux. And since I'm executing it in the JRE it only searches in the directory of the JRE and that's completely wrong of course. And since the library is taken from an Android App the original makefile probably had paths for the libraries that don't make sense either... have to do some more analysis for this question to be solved.

Comment: A library that is a symbolic link to an actual file works just like any other symbolic link. There must be some other problem that causes the error. As for the error, can you please copy-paste the actual error, in full and unedited, and show it in the question body? Perhaps also showing the command-line used for the linking (it is the linking that fails? Or does it fail when attempting to run your program?).

Answer (score 0):

The import should be `libm.so.6`. Importing `libm.so` should only be done while compiling. The resulting ELF should import the former.

This is called an ABI version. It is meant to make sure that if you linked with a library at a certain version, that you only get actual imports that are compatible with the version you linked with. There are somewhat complicated rules as to when that number changes (see [soname](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) for more details).

Sadly, you have not asked any actual question. This does not explain why your import failed. If the ELF header is wrong, then you are probably looking for it (more precisely, sending ld.so to look for it) at the wrong place.

I would run my code with `strace` to see what files are actually opened. Then, run `file` on it see that the platforms match (maybe a 64 bit executable is trying to open a 32 bit library or vice versa).

Comment: I analyzed the strace a bit more and it actually looks like the JRE finds all the libraries, opens them and closes them again. It even finds the right files on the right locations (it looks late but it looks at /usr/lib and there are all x64 lib files. I'm kinda back to step one again.